# GTM Timer Triggers

Tags: google-tag-manager

Following situation:
On a single page application, an event : ArticleClick is fired when we open a specific article on that page. I consider an article read when 10 seconds have passed after the ArticleClick event.

So far so good, this can be accomplished using the Timer functionality in GTM.

Only problem is that, when the event has fired and after 9 seconds i open another event, this will cause a second timer to start and no matter what i do as long as the website is open (because it's single page) there will always be a read event. Is there a simple way to stop the first timer when another article (and another timer) is opened before the 10 secs has reached?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using a datalayer variable to store the state of the timer (running or not).

Mind that the true or falses here are strings instead of booleans, this because the default value in GTM for the DL-variable needs to be set to false to make this work,doing that in the GTM-interface automatically makes the value a string.

```
<script>                           
(function() { 
var timerNumber = 1;
var limit = 1;
// timer
var fireTimer = function() {      
      window.dataLayer.push({
        'event' : 'ArticleRead',            
        'custom.timer.running' : 'false'
      });   
    timerNumber += 1;
    if (limit < timerNumber) { 
    window.clearInterval(timerId);
    }
    };  


   if ({{custom.timer.running}} == 'false') {


   window.dataLayer.push({ 'custom.timer.running' : 'true'});
   var timerId = window.setInterval(fireTimer, 10000);  }     

  })();
</script>
```

So now when we trigger the timer a second time and the timer hasn't reached it's 10000 milsecs it does not continue and it starts again.